# QGIS: How to turn symbol in polygon when using rotate tool

Tags: qgis, rotate

[image: QGIS rotate]

I would like the svg in the polygon to turn by using the rotate tool. [image: rotateSript]

Is there a script that will connect the layer layout with the rotate-tool?
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Open "Expression Builder" for "Rotation" property.

[image]

And use the following expression.

```
main_angle($geometry)-90
```

[image]

Comment: If this doesn't meet your need, please add more details about what exactly you need.

Comment: All the itms on the map are rotating around this point now. how can I make sure that each poygon has its own middle point to turn arroud?

Comment: Can you add an illustration showing what exactly you need?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible without some custom programming. Internal style rotations are separate from feature rotations.

You can set the rotation of style aspects based on some feature geometry rotation (check out the `main_angle()` expression function), but the other way around is not possible in a straight-forward way.